# Compiled Expression Trees misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, expression-trees

I have this expression :

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> f = s => s.Length < 5;
```

[image]

```
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter (typeof (string), "s");
MemberExpression stringLength = Expression.Property (p, "Length");
ConstantExpression five = Expression.Constant (5);
BinaryExpression comparison = Expression.LessThan (stringLength, five);
Expression<Func<string, bool>> lambda= Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>> (comparison, p);
```

//lets : test

```
Func<string, bool> runnable = lambda.Compile();
Console.WriteLine (runnable ("kangaroo")); // False
Console.WriteLine (runnable ("dog")); //True
```

I want to ask about the `.Compile()`

What does it compile ? And what is the difference between the first execution vs later executions...?

Compile should be something that happens once and not  happens again later ....

What / How does it help me ?

Comment: What tool did you use to generate this expression tree graph picture?

Comment: @Anastasiosyal its from a book http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ejU.jpg

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought I was missing some great visualiser for a moment. I guess, there is also [a wpf expression tree visualiser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83465/ExpressionTree-Visualizer-in-WPF) by @gcvcdcamp. An interesting project could be to make support rendering the expression tree as a graph using something like [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) although I can see how such a graph could get very busy quickly with any non trivial expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are building the expression tree at runtime there's no code emitted. It's a way to represent .NET code at runtime.

Once you call the `.Compile` method on the expression tree the actual IL code is emitted to convert this expression tree into a delegate (`Func<string, bool>` in your case) that you could invoke at runtime. So the code that this expression tree represents can be executed only after you compile it.

Calling Compile is an expensive operation. Basically you should be calling it once and then caching the resulting delegate that you could use to invoke the code many times.

Comment: In what "REAL" scenario will i ever use it ? ok... so im building expression at run time  , but its much harder and will contain a lot of IF's ( to build it).... can you please edit with real scenario where i need dynamically BUILD an expression ?

Comment: How did you mean the first statement? You mean that all 5 lines of code in first example will not have IL code, but will be transformed into Expression Tree directly? I dont believe compiler does optimalizations like this.

Answer (score 2):

The `Expression<Func<string,bool>>` is only a *representation* of an expression, it cannot be *executed*. Calling `Compile()` gives you a compiled delegate, a piece of code that you can call. Essentially, your program *composes* a small code snippet at runtime, and then call it as if it were processed by the compiler. This is what the last two lines of your code do: as you can see, the compiled snippet can analyze the length of the string that you pass in - when the length is less than five, you get a `True` back; when it's five or more, you get a `False`.

What happens on first execution of the compiled snippet is platform-dependent, and should not be detectable by programmers using the .NET platform.

Answer (score 2):

[`Compile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) takes the expression tree (which is a data representation of some logic) and converts it to IL which can then be executed directly as a delegate.

The only difference between the first execution and later executions is the possibility that `Compile()` won't trigger the JIT compilation from IL to native processor code. That *may* happen on first execution.